# Filtering the file content in Python is not working

Tags: python, character-encoding

This is my exercise
In the same directory with the source code is a file "strings.txt", which has random strings in several lines. The lines can be divided into two groups: those which only have letters (a-z, A-Z) and numbers (0-9), and those which also have random special characters (?,&,@, $ ...).

Create a program which reads all of the lines from the file and tests the lines. If the line has only letters and/or numbers, the program prints "[line] was ok.". If the line has special characters, the program should print "[line] was invalid.".

And this is the code which I have done:

```
handle = open("strings.txt","r")
content = handle.read()

for i in content:
    if i.rstrip().isalnum():
        print(i+" was ok.")
    else:
        print(i+" was invalid.")
file.close()
```

But it gives out this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ohjelma.py", line 2, in 
    content = handle.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is the desired output:

```
>>> 
5345m345ö34l was ok.
no2no123non4 was ok.
noq234n5ioqw#% was invalid.
%#""SGMSGSER was invalid.
doghdp5234 was ok.
sg,dermoepm was invalid.
43453-frgsd was invalid.
hsth())) was invalid.
bmepm35wae was ok.
vmopaem2234+0+ was invalid.
gsdm12313 was ok.
bbrbwb55be3"?"#? was invalid.
"?"#%#"!%#"&"?%%"?#?#"?" was invalid.
retrte#%#?% was invalid.
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxy was ok.
>>>
```

Comment: post the content of the strings. txt file you are trying to read

Comment: It seems your code is running under an ASCII locale but `strings.txt` contains characters outside the ASCII range.  Ideally we need to know the file's encoding.  However latin-1 or utf-8 would be good candidates, or cp1252 if the file was copied from a windows machine `open('strings.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Take a look at the [character-encoding tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) for some hints